# How to prove a derivative is measurable?

Tags: calculus

If f is differentiable, what can we say about f'? Continuous a.e or even measurable? I couldn't find anything online but was hoping for some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}$ we can show that the derivative is indeed Borel-measurable (also, see @AndreCaicedo's comment).
2. However, it needn't be continuous a.e., as demonstrated by the [Volterra function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).

Comment: Borel-measurable. In fact, preimages of open sets are $F_\sigma$.